# How to retweet specific user’s tweets with specific word only using IFTTT

Tags: if-this-then-that, retweet

I am looking for a recipe to retweet someones post only if a specific word was used (always at the beginning of the tweet if this is of any help).

I could not find ready to use recipe and creating one does not allow to chose specific word (only specific user).

Answer (score 1):

### Create your own applet!

You can use [IFTTT's platform](https://platform.ifttt.com/) (create you own IFTTT applets) to achieve that task.

With Platform, you can add a filter, written in JavaScript that will run between the trigger and the action(s).

So in your case, you can set the action for **New tweet by a specific user** from Twitter, than apply a JavaScript code to filter, and select the **Post a tweet** action.

#### About the JavaScript filtering:

- When you click to create a filter, you'll see a list <sup>[1]</sup> of variables/functions you can use, depending on the chosen trigger and action.
- Depends on your criteria, you can set the action to trigger or skip.
- A very simple JavaScript filtering example for the applet:

  ```
  if (Twitter.newTweetByUser.Text.indexOf("YOUR_PHRASE") != -1) {
      Twitter.postNewTweet.setTweet(Twitter.newTweetByUser.LinkToTweet);
  } else {
      Twitter.postNewTweet.skip();
  }
  ```

  - It will tweet the user's tweet if it contains `YOUR_PHRASE`.

<sup>[1]</sup> The available variables and functions for the chosen trigger and action:

> **Trigger data**
>   Twitter.newTweetByUser.Text
>   Twitter.newTweetByUser.UserName
>   Twitter.newTweetByUser.LinkToTweet
>   Twitter.newTweetByUser.TweetEmbedCode
>   Twitter.newTweetByUser.CreatedAt
>
> **Actions**
>   Twitter.postNewTweet.skip()
>   Twitter.postNewTweet.setTweet()
>
> **Other**
>   Meta.currentUserTime
>   Meta.triggerTime

#### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "New tweet from search" and then use specified Twitter search operators for example;

If new tweet from search ("@account" "#hashtag") then retweet...

*I use a little gmail work around to make sure the '@' tweets via IFTT - http://callismakesfilms.co.uk/blog/seo-marketing/ifttt-post-replies-twitterT

Comment: not hashtag - normal word